# How would I separate the JSON dictionary values and put them into a Swift array?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I'm am trying to return the Dictionary String values. It returns as:

> categories: [yelp1.Zom2(categories: yelp1.Zom3(name: "Delivery")), yelp1.Zom2(categories: yelp1.Zom3(name: "Dine-out"))....]

How would I only return the name values such as "Delivery" and "Dine-Out"?
//yelp1 is just the name of the file

SAMPLE JSON DATA

```
{
    "categories": [
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Delivery"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dine-out"
      }
    },
```

THESE ARE MY STRUCTS

```
struct Zom3:Codable{
    let name:String
}
struct Zom2:Codable{

    //let category_id:Int?
    let categories: Zom3

}
struct Zom:Codable{

    //let category_id:Int?
    let categories: [Zom2]

}
```

I have tried to decode Zom3 because thats where the name value is located but it states key not found. It won't allow me to iterate through with a for loop to at least get each element of the dictionary individually.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlName = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/categories"
    let url = URL(string: urlName)
    var urlReq = URLRequest(url: url!)
    urlReq.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlReq.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    urlReq.addValue(zomatoKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "user_key")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlReq) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let items = try JSONDecoder().decode( Zom.self, from: data)
            print(items)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've written, it looks like your output is from your "print(items)" line. If that's true, then the object you've called "items" is the top level struct "Zom". To get the bottom level "name" I think you do need a for loop under "let items = try..."; (instead of "print(items)")

```swift
var arrayOfNames: [String] = []
let zoms = item.categories
for item in zoms {
    let possibleName = item.categories?.name
    if let name = possibleName {
         arrayOfNames.append(name)
    }
}
print(arrayOfNames)
```

If I haven't made any mistakes this should create an array of the names and print out "Delivery, Dine-Out"

Comment: I've tried to use a for loop before and I just tried this. It states "Type 'Zom' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'".

Comment: I've just edited - I missed drilling down one level sorry. Try now?

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. I just had to make Zom3 optional also. Thank you for your help